# WCF Data Service Login Failed

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2005, wcf-data-services

I am using WCF Data Services in the following environment:

IIS 7
Windows 7
.NET 4.0
Entity Framework 5.0
SQL Server 2005

The WCF Data Service is accessible at:

```
http://localhost:81/DataService/WcfDataService.svc
```

However when I enter the following I get an error:

```
http://localhost:81/DataService/WcfDataService.svc/EntityName(1)
```

Why is the data service trying to connect using the computer name and not the network user name?

```
-<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">

<m:code/>

<m:message xml:lang="de-DE">An error occurred while processing this request.</m:message>


-<m:innererror>

<m:message>The underlying provider failed on Open.</m:message>

<m:type>System.Data.EntityException</m:type>

<m:stacktrace> at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetEnumeratorInternal() at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() at System.Data.Services.WebUtil.GetRequestEnumerator(IEnumerable enumerable) at System.Data.Services.QueryResultInfo.MoveNext() at System.Data.Services.Providers.DataServiceExecutionProviderWrapper.GetSingleResultFromRequest(SegmentInfo segmentInfo) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CompareETagAndWriteResponse(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService, IODataResponseMessage responseMessage) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.SerializeResponseBody(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService, IODataResponseMessage responseMessage) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleNonBatchRequest(RequestDescription description) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()</m:stacktrace>


-<m:internalexception>

<m:message>Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\COMPUTERNAME$'.</m:message>

<m:type>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException</m:type>

<m:stacktrace> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)</m:stacktrace>

</m:internalexception>

</m:innererror>

</m:error>
```

Comment: Can you share your connection string in web.config?

Comment: I switched to LINQ to Entities instead of getting WCF Data Services to work. Will update this post shortly.